# redis: batch inserting using joblib

Tags: redis, joblib

I have a list of my records. For each of my records I need to to a somewhat heavy calculation as I'm creating a reversed index in redis. For reach record multiple redis commands are executed in a pipe (100s of `sadd` + 1 `set`).

I want to parallelize this index creation part (using joblib) but failing to do so. First issue was that I wanted to pass in the redis connection to each job but that doesn't work as joblib wants to serialize it which doesn't work. So just submit the host/port and have each porcess create it's own connection.

```
def heavy_calc_insert(value, host, port)

    r = redis.Redis(host=host, port=port)

    #... some calc

    pipe = r.pipeline()

    for bit in bits:
        key = "bit:" + str(bit)
        pipe.sadd(key, idx_value)

    pipe.set(idx_value, id)
    pipe.execute()

Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(heavy_calc_insert)(value, host, port) for value in values)
```

However with this code I rather quickly get a `ConnectionError`:

```
ConnectionError: Connection closed by server.
```

I assume I hit sone form of having too many connections.

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use a connection pool. https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/README.rst#connection-pools

Create the pool out of the heavy_calc_insert, and pass the pool instead of host and port.

```
pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host=host, port=port, db=0)
...
def heavy_calc_insert(value, pool)
    r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
    ...
```

Redis has a default 10,000 connections limit, and it doesn't close unused connections.

A connection pool will keep the connections created under control and give you better performance as well.

Comment: I've actually read all that already and as far as I understood redis.Redis creates a connection pool already and there is no way to close connections so that the limit isn't reached. EDIT: And I did already try passing the pool but the pool has the same serialization issue as well.

Comment: If you tried as in the code example (just edited answer), please add redis, redis-py, and python versions. See https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/1127 and https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/1140

Comment: neither redis nor pool can be used with joblib as they can't be serialized.